# How to send a delayed auto reply to received SMS

Tags: android, sms

What I want to do is have the app triggered by any incoming text message while the app is active. Upon receiving the SMS, I want it to have a delay (set by the user) in seconds before it sends an auto-reply automatically without the user's intervention.

What I have so far is:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //---get the SMS message passed in---        
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();                  
    if (bundle != null)        {           
        //assuming the message exists... what to do now?      
        }
}
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this, so if there is any available that anyone knows of, please link. Or if there is a good example, please answer with as well.

To clarify, I'm looking for 2 things --
1) How to do the delay
2) How to do the auto-reply

Answer (score 1):

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        //Send code for automatice message response

    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Take object of handler as global and use it above way

Comment: I see the delay portion, do you have any suggestions for the actual sending of the SMS in reply?

Comment: Check out this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Android AlaramManager` to do the task.(which won't work at times)

or else you can run a `timer loop` to do the delay(which is less preferable coz it holds lots of memory).

or you can use an `Asynchronous thread` to run the task with a delay.

The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

```
@Override
public void run() {

    // code for reply of SMS

}

    }, DelayOfReplySMSTime);
```